# How to isolate multiple 24 VAC to 5 VDC power supplies (buck converters) that are all powered by a single main transformer with a common pole?

Tags: power-electronics, gpio, testing, troubleshooting, gpio-external-interrupt

Basically, I am trying to test multiple relay controlled outputs that are all 24 V outputs. One pole of the transformer is going into a relay for each device and the other side of each device is common. In order to automate the testing of this device I am using multiple 24 VAC to 5 VDC power supplies (or buck converters) that output to a GPIO input that will read high or low based on the device being turned on or not.

The problem I am having is that because all of the buck converters share a common wire on the AC side and are all hooked up to the same GPIO device (with a common ground for pull downs), when I turn on one, they all turn on or the high signal changes which input its sending the signal to.

I believe that this is because the common wires are allowing back current into the system and sending current to the wrong input. I believe that I need to isolate the common wire on the AC side somehow in order to prevent this but I'm not quite sure how to go about it in a solid state way.

This is the schematic that I am using to do this so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsR1y1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In theory I should be able to add however many of these circuits to the system and be able to read from each of them. So why am I getting back current and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Your schematic is drawn incorrectly.  The AC inputs of the converters are shorted together.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: By default a "buck converter" is not isolated. If you want isolated buck converters you need to buy/specify/build them specifically.

Comment: As far as the schematic goes im aware that it shows the AC inputs shorted together but I was having problems showing that the wire went over it, thus why i colored that wire a different color.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-obvious way was to use opto-couplers.

Not to *prevent back current*, but to signal *24 V AC present* to an isolated level.

Comment: Yes, "GPIO" is a level different from *24 V AC*. But a *buck converter* is neither a *level shifter*, nor does it isolate.